# Getting the z-index of a DIV in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, z-index

I have a div `normaldiv1` with class `normaldiv`.
I am trying to access its z-index through the style property but it always returns 0 although it's set to 2 in the stylesheet.

CSS:

```
.normaldiv
{
    width:120px; 
    height:50px; 
    background-color:Green;  
    position: absolute;
    left: 25px;
    top:20px;
    display:block;
    z-index:2;
}
```

`

HTML:

```
<div id="normaldiv1" 
     class="normaldiv" 
     newtag="new" 
     tagtype="normaldiv1" 
     onmousedown="DivMouseDown(this.id);" 
     ondblclick="EditCollabobaTag(this.id,1);" 
     onclick="GetCollabobaTagMenu(this.id);" 
     onblur="RemoveCollabobaTagMenu(this.id);">
```

JavaScript:

```
alert(document.getElementById('normaldiv1').style.zIndex);
```

How can I find the z-index of an element using JavaScript?

Comment: I would really recommend using a library like jQuery or Prototype to help

Answer (score 25):

Since z index is mentioned in the CSS part you won't be able to get it directly through the code that you have mentioned. You can use the following example.

```
function getStyle(el,styleProp)
{
    var x = document.getElementById(el);

    if (window.getComputedStyle)
    {
        var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(x,null).getPropertyValue(styleProp); 
    }  
    else if (x.currentStyle)
    {
        var y = x.currentStyle[styleProp];
    }                     

    return y;
}
```

pass your element id and style attribute to get to the function.

Eg:

```
var zInd = getStyle ( "normaldiv1" , "zIndex" );
alert ( zInd );
```

**For firefox you have to pass z-index instead of zIndex**

```
var zInd = getStyle ( "normaldiv1" , "z-index" );
 alert ( zInd );
```

[Reference](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html)

Comment: +1 but "style" is misleading. You *can* read directly it if it's inline declared, you can't if it's CSS declared. It's the CSS part which matters.

Comment: Better not to use non-standard `currentStyle` before standard `getComputedStyle`.

Comment: IE8: says `document.defaultView` doesn't exists and neither `[element].currentStyle` (Object doesn't support this property or method)

Comment: Thank you!  This is so useful for debugging.

Comment: In case anyone is interested jQuery equivalent:
`$.fn.cssComputed = function (prop)
{
    var elm = this.get(0);
    var style = "";

    if (window.getComputedStyle)
    {
        style = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elm, null).getPropertyValue(prop);
    }
    else if (elm.currentStyle)
    {
        style = elm.currentStyle[prop];
    }

    return style;
}
`

Answer (score 11):

try this

```
window.getZIndex = function (e) {      
  var z = window.getComputedStyle(e).getPropertyValue('z-index');
  if (isNaN(z)) return window.getZIndex(e.parentNode);
  return z; 
};
```

usage

```
var myZIndex = window.getZIndex($('#myelementid')[0]);
```

(if parent gets to root it will return 0)

Comment: this works great!
```window.document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(e).getPropertyValue('z-index');```

Comment: It's not; `window.document.defaultView` is the same as `window`; and you can drop `window.` in all of these cases as well.

Comment: doesn't work for me, it gets the z-index of element in the element's stacking context, but I want z-index in the document's stacking context, see this for probably correct implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930224/determine-absolute-or-global-z-index

Comment: Citing MDN: In many code samples, getComputedStyle is used from the document.defaultView object. In nearly all cases, this is needless, as getComputedStyle exists on the window object as well. It's likely the defaultView pattern was a combination of folks not wanting to write a testing spec for window and making an API that was also usable in Java.