# Determine absolute or global z-index?

Tags: javascript, z-index

OK guys, here's a tricky one (perhaps):  is there any to get a sort of "global z-index" of an element?  here is an example of what i'd like to do:

given two element references, how would you determine which one is higher in the z order (given that they may not have assigned z-indices or are in separated containers)

Elaborate hacks welcome!  Not-so elaborate methods *more* than welcome.

Comment: What do you mean? Either they have `z-index` values or they don't. If they don't, then they don't have a "global z-index" and if they do, their "global z-index" value is just their `z-index`

Comment: @davin:  many elements are not assigned an explicit z-index, or inherit the z-index of their parent.  even so - all elements on the page have a "global z-index" of some sort - if all elements were postioned over one another, they would have a non-random stacking order.  however, I do not know of any way to determine which element is on top.

Comment: You might find http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index helpful, especially the description of the order in which elements are rendered.

Comment: @davin: alas that is not true. The question is about what in 3d apps is called the z-buffer.  Sometimes you might want to know what element the user of the browser is actual seeing. And sometimes loads of elements are overlapping. Overlapping because they are inside a div or have z-index or have a position:static/sticky/whatever. Alas html/css is total wack about z-buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an interesting problem. The following code may not be bug free. I just put it together right now and haven't tested it entirely. Its purpose is to demonstrate an approach.

It compares two elements and tests them on three criteria:

- Looking through the ancestor tree of each element, if the first ancestor for element A to have a z-index has a greater z-index than the first ancestor of element B to have a z-index (if one exists for element B at all), then element A is higher in the z-order.
- Otherwise, if element B is a descendent of element A then element B has a higher z-order.
- Otherwise, looking at the siblings of the last ancestor that element A and element B had in common, if an ancestor of element A comes first in the array of children of that common ancestor then element B has a higher z order.

There may be an simpler way of describing of the logic above and the algorithm can be improved. (For example, the second check above could be done first.) However, here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">

function getAncestorsAsArray(element){
    var arr = new Array();
    arr.unshift(element);
    while (arr[0].parentNode){
        arr.unshift(arr[0].parentNode);
    }

    return arr;
}

function highestInitialZIndex(elementArr){
    for (var i=0; i<elementArr.length; i++){
        if (elementArr[i].style == undefined) continue;
        var r = elementArr[i].style.zIndex;
        if (!isNaN(r) && r!="") {
            return r;
        }
    }

    return undefined;
}

function findCommonAncestor(elementArr1, elementArr2){
    var commonAncestor;
    for (var i=0; i<elementArr1.length; i++){
        if (elementArr1[i] == elementArr2[i]) {
            commonAncestor = elementArr1[i];
        }
    }

    return commonAncestor;
}

function findHighestAbsoluteIndex(element1, element2){
    var arr1 = getAncestorsAsArray(element1);
    var arr2 = getAncestorsAsArray(element2);

    // Does an ancestor of one elment simply have a higher z-index?
    var arr1Z = highestInitialZIndex(arr1);
    var arr2Z = highestInitialZIndex(arr2);
    if (arr1Z > arr2Z || (!isNaN(arr1Z) && isNaN(arr2Z))) return element1;
    if (arr2Z > arr1Z || (!isNaN(arr2Z) && isNaN(arr1Z))) return element2;

    // Is one element a descendent of the other?
    var commonAncestor = findCommonAncestor(arr1, arr2);
    if (commonAncestor == element1) return element2;
    if (commonAncestor == element2) return element1;

    // OK, which has the oldest common sibling? (Greater index of child node for an element = "older" child)
    var indexOfCommonAncestor;
    for (var i=0; i<arr1.length; i++){
        if (arr1[i] == commonAncestor) {
            indexOfCommonAncestor = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    for (var j=commonAncestor.childNodes.length; j>=0; j--){
        if (arr1[indexOfCommonAncestor+1] == commonAncestor.childNodes[j]) return element1;
        if (arr2[indexOfCommonAncestor+1] == commonAncestor.childNodes[j]) return element2;
    }   
}

function doTest(){
    var e1 = document.getElementById("myDiv1");
    var e2 = document.getElementById("myDiv2");

    highest = findHighestAbsoluteIndex(e1, e2);
    alert(highest.id);
}

</script>

</head>
<body onload="javascript:doTest();">

<div>
<div>
<div style="position:absolute; z-index:20;" id="myDiv1">
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div>
</div>

<div style="position:absolute; z-index:10;" id="myDiv2">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Play around with the nested `div`s in the body to test it working.

Comment: works out of the box - about as much as I can ask for from strangers on the internet - Thanks!

Comment: Elements with `position:static` (all elements without an explicit `position` are static) will always appear before positioned-elements with a non-negative `z-index` (or no `z-index`), regardless of their `z-index` value if any. This should take this into account. Also, amongst static elements - floating elements are above the rest, and inline elements are above all other. (Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index for more information).

Comment: @YuvalA. Good catch. Feel free to improve the code!

Comment: There are many more things that create stacking contexts than z-index, e.g. transform: translateZ

Comment: Highly insane that this is not a js function. Flash had this in 1980.