# Multiple Bootstrap Modals opens onLoad but class modal-backdrop transparency layer is not overlapping on each of the modal

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to achieve Multiple Bootstrap Modals opens **onLoad** currently it opens perfectly fine **onClick** even on each of the modal button however we have some TIMEOUT WARNING, which comes on load so for that we need modal works **onLoad** as well

During the investigation found that **class modal-backdrop** transparency layer is not overlapping means based on the modals z-index is not increases, and requirement from my client is that If user launch modal onClick or onLoad the user may see multiple bootstrap modals depending upon the scenario, example: If user click on "Cancel" button user will be promote in modal say "Hey, Are you sure you want to cancel" but at the same time might get modal onLoad addressed "TimeOut Warning" from server

Below are the screenshot for `onLoad` and `onClick` behavior scenarios

This is the behavior onLoad transparency layer are not coming on each of the below modals but onClick multiple modals works perfectly fine:
[image: This is the behavior onLoad transparency layer are not coming on each of the below modals but onClick multiple modals works perfectly fine]

Here I also Atrached `jsFiddle`: http://jsfiddle.net/CxdUQ/314

Comment: i tried it with bs4 and it works

Comment: Hi @Leandro Ruel, but we have integrated with bs3, any solution in that?

Comment: Is Anyone able to help me out on this?

Comment: how about loop every ".modal-backdrop" and adding more z-index, like 1050 + 1, and +2 to the next... so i think it will work.

Comment: get the z-index of modal, and apply to the modal-backdrop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388007/getting-the-z-index-of-a-div-in-javascript

Comment: Hello,If you notice in Fiddle - (http://jsfiddle.net/CxdUQ/314/) I am doing the same thing in my code  var zIndex = 1040 + (10 * $('.modal:visible').length), but that works onClick but not onLoad, any other suggestion, would be really appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: why ":visible" in ```.modal``` ?

Comment: If you have any solution, would you able to Fiddle it up?

Answer (score 0):

i found [this question that already have a answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305821/multiple-modals-overlay) for this, and here is your jsfiddle with the changes: http://jsfiddle.net/CxdUQ/

the following code is the answer found at link provided above:

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
    var zIndex = 1040 + (10 * $('.modal:visible').length);
    $(this).css('z-index', zIndex);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.modal-backdrop').not('.modal-stack').css('z-index', zIndex - 1).addClass('modal-stack');
    }, 0);
});
```

Comment: It works button onClick but how do we achieve onLoad method for multiple modals that is what i am looking for, Any solution for this?